# I keep getting logged in to another user account

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, auto-login

My friend logged in on my computer with his account once and since that time I cannot log in with my credentials without being logged in to his account... I think, that my email address got somehow associated with his account, but there is no option to remove it. And even if there was such an option, I do not understand why did this happen.

Could someone please tell me, how to restore my account to its former independence?

Also I keep getting automatically logged in and I have to delete the cookies after each logout... This behavior is stupid - when I log out, I want to be logged out, not actually get autologged in all the time. Really annoying...

Comment: I think if you look at "my logins" on your profile page you'll see an extra email address on your account. There should be a remove button for you there.

Comment: I thought the same and the address is there, but there is no such button :( Only the 'change password' and 'add more logins...' buttons.

Comment: Ah I thought that might be a safety feature to prevent me from breaking your account.

Comment: Looking into this now - operation separating conjoined friends is _underway_

Comment: Re-sent email to the proper address, I should have this sorted out quickly

Comment: Actually I think I found the issue. Can you try again? (with any luck, you're responding to this thread as yourself after logging in)

Comment: Nope... Still my friends account. And the email address is still there. Plus the autologin still making me unsure whether I did actually log out or not... Anyway I'm going to respond you an email with the details, OK?

Comment: We're going to need to pull in a specialist for this one. Dr. Nick Craver to the O.R. **STAT**

Comment: I'm not sure about what you meant by the last comment, but I sent you my email response - hope that helps to solve this.

Comment: Nick's another developer. Tim just means Nick's going to look at it.

Comment: I have...done things...to your accounts - can you please try logging in now?

Comment: OK... Some error giving pages later, I have successfuly logged in as ME. But I have lost all my points, which is sad... Actually I could have just created a new profile and associate it with another email with similar results :(

Comment: You should be good to go now - please give it a try :)

Comment: Ahh wait... Now I have some points! Not sure if it's the same amount as before, but at least I can upvote downvote and stuff. Thanks for your time very much! Now I can get to actually posting my question!

Comment: OK, so now it looks it's working fine except that I still can't log in to the EE forums... It's giving me that burnt chip error page whenever I try to log in.

Comment: Give us a few to get that sorted.

Comment: @MatoušVrba Should be all sorted now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was .. an *extremely* narrow fluke that resulted in your accounts being automatically merged by the system due to having the same credentials associated with both. We're now looking into exactly how that happened, and possibly getting something into place to prevent it from happening in the future.

Sorry about the confusion, but the surgery was successful and you can both now live long and more importantly *independent* lives.

I'll leave it to Nick to mark this completed, but wanted to give a short reply as to what happened.

Comment: Well thank you a lot, you were very helpful, but please if you only fixed the EE forum error... And the Raspberry Pi BETA has the same problem.

And I am sad to be unable to actually accept or upvote your answer...

Comment: We're looking at that now - hang tight.

Comment: Super! One more big thank for your help! As I can see, my friend has already accepted this, therefore everything is correct!